# How do I use a single list to populate navbar with icon and names?

Tags: reactjs

So the issue is I am trying to use a list to populate my navbar. I have tried many different renditions of this and I cannot understand what it is that I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone tell me if this is even possible?

```
import {home} from './img/home.svg'
import {portfolio} from './img/portfolio.svg'
import {resume} from './img/resume.svg'
import {contact} from './img/contact.svg'

const navigation = [
  {img: {home}, link: "Home"},
  {img: {portfolio}, link: "Portfolio"},
  {img: {resume}, link:"Living Resume"},
  {img: {contact}, link: "Contact"}
]

function Navbar (props){
  
  const links = props.navlinks;
  const navList = links.map((link)=> <li>
    <a href={link.link}>
      <img src={link.img} alt = {link.link}/>
       {link.link}
       </a>
       </li>)
  return(
    <nav className="fixed navbar-1">
      <div className="text-center m-3 h-2/6">
        <a href="/" className="logo -space-y-3 ">
          <p>J</p>
          <p className="ml-4">W</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul className="space-y-8">
      {navList}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
   <>
   <Navbar navlinks={navigation}/>
   
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

they aren't rendering I'm getting this error `Failed to compile.  ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'contact' is not exported from './img/contact.svg'.  –`

Comment: Code looks fine, other than using anchor tags (`<a />`) and the links not really looking like they link to anything, what is the issue you're having? Clicking anchor tags will typically reload your app, so perhaps that is what you are seeing?

Comment: Do not follow the question, what is the problem you are facing? The listing does not render? You can try "links.map((link)=> <li>" to add key, which is "links.map((link,i)=> <li key={i}>". But even without you should be able to render still...